# can flutter sdk run on x86 windows?

Tags: windows, x86, dart, flutter

Has anybody tried and succeeded with installing flutter on win x86?
(no VM of course)

My question is not about what Google SAYs, but why do YOU think it is possible or not possible. I do not see anything in the source at github that may prevent it from running on win x86 apart that google does not want to provide support for x86, because it is not a priority.

If you think it is not possible, can you please provide some idea why before saying No or voting down

====BACKGROUND====

prerequisites for the flutter sdk on windows are:

- dart 2.0
- PowerShell 5.0 or newer
- Git for Windows

inside there are also some java and libcurl executables 
all of the above exist in win x86 versions
plus the rest seems to be just dart source code.

I run flutter on Ubuntu.
I have an older laptop with win 7 x86 pro which I do not want to upgrade to x64

I tried to use x64 win installation
replacing dart 2.0 x64->x86

and then using flutter doctor to update.
(flutter uses dart pub with "update" function changed to "upgrade", but this can be fixed)

the update using flutter doctor in fact runs just to the point of updating flutter_tool

then trying to update some flutter_tool related packages it comes up with an ERROR:

> cannot resolve the library URL

Comment: yes, it's very much possible, i've tried it on windows, linux and OS X too.

Comment: @Qasim if you were able to run it on win x86 could you please explain more in detail how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Windows installation page](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/) says:

> To install and run Flutter, your development environment must meet
>   these minimum requirements:
>
> - Operating Systems: Windows 7 SP1 or later **(64-bit)**

And there is a [recent comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14925#issuecomment-414414191) (20 Aug 2018) from one of the Flutter developers that also states:

> We don't have any plans to support 32-bit Windows. That said, if
>   anyone is willing to send pull requests to get Flutter running on
>   32-bit Windows, we'd gladly review the PRs.

A [further response](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14925#issuecomment-415864259) from the Flutter devs outlines some of the reasons why this is the case:

> 1. Someone would need to author 32-bit build rules in the
>      engine/buildroot repos to build a 32-bit SDK -- specifically the
>      Dart VM and gen_snapshot. Ideally, the rules would also emit the
>      target architecture Android artifacts as well.
> 2. The design of gen_snapshot (our AOT compiler) assumes identical host
>      and target architecture bitness. Only a 64-bit build of gen_snapshot
>      can output arm64 target binaries. Fixing this would involve a
>      significant amount of work.

Comment: My question was not about what they SAY, but why do YOU think it is posiible or not possible. I do not see anything in the source at github that may prevent it from running on win x86 apart that google do not want provide support for x86. I also suspect that providing the proper insallation on x86 is not difficult for people who know "the gutts" it is just not a priority. This is why I want to know if anybody have already found how to do it on x86.

Comment: @yus: I'm not familiar with flutter at all, but that statement from the developer sounds pretty clear.  It's not just that they don't *support* or choose to distribute packages for 32-bit Windows, the wording implies that it would take at least some minor source changes to make it build.  So like they said, feel free to modify the source yourself and send in your patches.  When you chose 32-bit Win7, you chose poorly. :(  32-bit x86 has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: @Herohtar: Thank you for the link to flutter: Get Started: Install page: where I joined you question to cbracken of flutter team

Comment: @yus Updated my answer with the response from the dev about why it doesn't work on 32-bit systems.